# LINQ group by and max clause usage

Tags: linq

I have below Employee class which has 3 important fields

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Department
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double Salary
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I have a list of such employees.  I want to find out name employee from each department
whose salary is maximum in his/her department.

I Wrote below query but its not working.

```
List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
        list.Add(new Employee { Name="Hemant",Salary=10,Department="PTS"});
        list.Add(new Employee { Name = "Gunjan", Salary = 11, Department = "PTS" });
        list.Add(new Employee { Name = "Akshay", Salary = 8, Department = "PTS" });
        list.Add(new Employee { Name = "Omkar", Salary = 10, Department = "EBG" });
        list.Add(new Employee { Name = "Hemant1", Salary = 14, Department = "EBG" });

        var query1 = from e in list
                    group e by e.Department into g
                    select new { Dept = g.Key,MaxSal = g.Max((e) => e.Salary )};

        foreach (var item in query1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Department : " + item.Dept + "  :  " + " Salary is : " + item.MaxSal);                
        }
```

But above piece of code is not working, I am not able to select employee name.  I think I must use ascending/descending clause and select first or last record.  But I am not able to figure it out.  Can someone help.

Regards,
Hemant Shelar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should `OrderByDescending` and then get `First`:

```
var query1 = list.GroupBy(x => x.Department)
                 .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Salary).First());
```

Below is console code:

```
foreach (var item in query1)
{
    string output = string.Format("Deparment: {0}, Name: {1}, Max Salaray: {2}",
                                  item.Department, item.Name, item.Salary
        );

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks perfectly what I was expecting.  Now I am trying to convert this to equivalent LINQ query :)

Comment: @user2243747: you don't need to do this, I always feel that lambda syntax simpler and easier to use. Under the hood, linq syntax will be converted to lambda syntax.